# Verifying whether the Image has been generated or not using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, casperjs

I am unable to verify for the image which will be generated after executing code.
Below is the HTML code:

```
    <div class="live-plot-container">
    <div class="live-plot">
        <div class="live-plot-scroller">
            <div class="ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide" style="width: 510px; height: 510px;">
                <img id="wk21uyp50py5v3z5dl890x0ue-1"
                     src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAf4AAAH+CAYAAAB9b2wlAAAgAElEQVR4nOzdd3gU1foH8O/MbM1m00N6IQmBUBNCaKFJCUWKoGJBERUriBX9XRXkig0vV8EKqAjY8YpKk94EpBNKCIGEllBCCQnpu9k9vz82u0lI22x2d7K77+d5eHRnzsx5Z3az786Zc85wjDEGQgghhLgEXuwACCGEEGI/lPgJIYQQF0KJnxBCCHEhlPgJIYQQF0KJnxBCCHEhlPgJIYQQF0KJnzSK4zhwHGfXOuxRpz3raa7ii39hTPc2UMokULh7ih2OKMT6jBDibCjxuxjjl6XxnyBTwi8wAn2H3Y1/f/4rblToxQ6R1GHJyEewcn8mnl1zEsV5l8zaRleajW/eewmDe3SEn4cbJIIUHj7B6D5wHN5fvAFakWbwMH72Bi45VW+Zi5vvp8ROiI1Q4ndRjDEwxlBRfBPHd/2JJwaG45uXH0Rk1ECsv...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"
                     style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90; display: none;"></div>
                <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90; display: none;"></div>
                <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se"
                     style="z-index: 90; display: none;"></div>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
<span class="live-plot-commands" style="display: none;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is CasperJs code

```
casper.then(function (){
    var temp = this.getElementInfo('#wk21uyp50py5v3z5dl890x0ue-1');
    this.echo(temp);
    this.test.assertExists("#wk21uyp50py5v3z5dl890x0ue-1");
})
```

I am trying to check for the image which has generated with the unique selector, and when i run the script following error is displayed in command line/Terminal

> FAIL Cannot get informations from #wk21uyp50py5v3z5dl890x0ue-1: element not found.
> type: uncaughtError
>
> file: VerifyImage.js
>
> FAIL Cannot get informations from #wk21uyp50py5v3z5dl890x0ue-1: element not found.
>
> stack: not provided
>
> FAIL 9 tests executed in 88.737s, 8 passed, 1 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.

Comment: Have you taken a screenshot to see if the image is generated? Have you tried waiting (`casper.waitForSelector()`) for the image to appear? How do you trigger the appearance of the image? Is the *unique* ID a problem? Does the ID change between executions? Please [edit] your question and be more specific.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I am not running it in headless so that i can see the steps/operation of the script and also i can see the image. Coming to ID part, it is same every time and its not dynamic. before this script i have provided enough wait and also used `casper.waitForSelector()`.

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't show you using `casper.waitForSelector()`. Can you show your full casper script, or at least some more of it.  (My guess is that `then()` is not executing at the point you think it is.)

Comment: Is it in an iframe? If so, you need to change to the frame first with `casper.withFrame()`

Comment: @ArtjomB.How do i get to know whether its in iFrame or not?